# Python Unit Test Dependent Functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I'm using pytest to write some unit tests, and wondering what the best approach for testing 'dependent' functions are. Let's say I have two functions:

```
def set_file(filename, filecontents):
    # stores file as key in memcache

def get_file(filename):
    # returns the contents of the filename if it exists in cache
```

Currently, I have a 'happy path' unit test that looks something like this:

```
def test_happy_path():
    assert not get_file('unit test') # check that return of non-existent file is None
    set_file('unit test', 'test content') # set file contents
    assert get_file('unit test') == 'test content'  # check that return matches input
```

My question is whether this approach is valid? Should I be trying to mock data of `set_file` when testing `get_file` to have a unit test that has no dependancies created by `set file`? If so, how would I mock that, especially since `set_file` is using pymemcached?

Comment: As for me, your `test_happy_path` seems to be valid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unit test looks perfectly valid. There's no harm in setting files to `pymemcache` during tests because everything remains in local memory. It's also perfectly ok to have such "setup" dependencies in your tests.

If you notice that you start to have multiple tests dependending on the same setup, you can use [pytest fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html) for setting up such setup and teardown dependencies. Example code could look like this:

```py
import pytest

FILENAME = "test-file"
TEST_CONTENT = "some content"


@pytest.fixture()
def set_file_contents():
    assert not get_file(FILENAME)
    set_file(FILENAME, TEST_CONTENT)
    yield FILENAME, TEST_CONTENT  # These values are provided to the test
    delete_file(FILENAME)  # This is run after the test
    assert not get_file(FILENAME)


class TestFileContents:

    def test_get_file(self, set_file_contents):
        filename, file_contents = set_file_contents
        assert get_file(filename) == file_contents
```

Using fixtures is an overkill in your case but you see the basic idea.

Comment: I just realized that if you're connecting to an external ``memcached`` database in your code, you definitely need to either mock or use a test database. Mocking should be easy by using [MockMemcacheClient](https://pymemcache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apidoc/pymemcache.test.utils.html#module-pymemcache.test.utils) from ``pymemcache`` in your application code when testing.